# How to extract specific value from list of list of dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, types

I'm trying to extract the value of "Alt_name" and need to store it as a list.

**Input:**

```
[
 [{'Name': 'Selin', 'Age': '31', 'Active': 'true', 'Items': '4', 'Alt_name': 'selin-hub', 'type': 'Normal', 'Colour':'Blue'}],
 [{'Name': 'Jenny', 'Age': '21', 'Active': 'true', 'Items': '2', 'Alt_name': 'jenny-cean', 'type': 'Normal', 'Colour': 'green'}],
 [{'Name': 'Vuly', 'Age': '20', 'Active': 'true', 'Items': '3', 'Alt_name': 'clary', 'type': 'Normal'}] 
]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 ['selin-hub','jenny-cean','clary']
```

How to extract the value of  Alt_name from the above input?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list of lists, each containing a dictionary. So, just rifle through the lists, choosing the first element (the dictionary), then choosing the `'Alt_name'` field.

Setting your list to the variable `l`, you could find the desired output by using a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
[d[0]['Alt_name'] for d in l]
```

If you can modify this list, you might consider just making it a list of dictionaries, i.e.:

```
l = [
    {'Name': 'Selin', 'Age': '31', 'Active': 'true', 'Items': '4', 'Alt_name': 'selin-hub', 'type': 'Normal', 'Colour':'Blue'},
    {'Name': 'Jenny', 'Age': '21', 'Active': 'true', 'Items': '2', 'Alt_name': 'jenny-cean', 'type': 'Normal', 'Colour': 'green'},
    {'Name': 'Vuly', 'Age': '20', 'Active': 'true', 'Items': '3', 'Alt_name': 'clary', 'type': 'Normal'}
]
```

in which case you could obtain the desired output by writing

```
[d['Alt_name'] for d in l]
```